# Retain screen brightness settings after resuming from suspend

Tags: release-hera, suspend, brightness

I'm using:

- a 2013 27" iMac + secondary monitor
- elementary OS 5.1.6 Hera

When resuming from suspend, the brightness of the main screen is at maximum rather than my custom setting. The brightness control widget indicates the custom setting (not maximum), and any adjustment using that or the keyboard controls will restore it to the correct custom setting.

Any suggests as to the cause?